# How to mention individual sheet names while writing mutiple org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset into an .xls file using crealytics / spark-excel in java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset, rdd, spark-excel

I am trying to write different Java Datasets into an excel file which will contain multiple sheets inside it using crealytics/spark-excel library.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.crealytics</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-excel_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

How do I provide a name for those individual excel sheets?

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;

SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("LineQuery").getOrCreate();

Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM my_table1");
Dataset<Row> df2 = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM my_table2");

df1.write().format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("sheetName","My Sheet 1").option("header", "true").save("hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/" + outFile + ".xls");

df2.write().format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("sheetName","My Sheet 2").option("header", "true").mode(SaveMode.Append).save("hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/" + outFile + ".xls");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dataAddress` option instead

Example:

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(11, 12), (21, 22)])
>>> df.show()
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
| 11| 12|
| 21| 22|
+---+---+
>>> df.where("_1 == 11").write.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("dataAddress", "my sheet 1[#All]").option("header", "true").mode("append").save("/tmp/excel-df.xlsx")
>>> df.where("_1 == 21").write.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("dataAddress", "my sheet 2[#All]").option("header", "true").mode("append").save("/tmp/excel-df.xlsx")
```